# WPF/Silverlight: VisualStateManager vs Triggers?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I see there's some overlap in functionality between the visual state manager and triggers.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
      <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
             ... bla bla ...
      </VisualState>
  </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Or I could go

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
          ... bla bla ...
</Trigger>
```

When should I use one vs the other?

Comment: One time I added custom VisualState "NoItems". It would be easier with triggers.

Answer (score 13):

### Why use VisualStateManager and (not, eventually) use Triggers?

Let's start with the general differences between them.

- **How they are fired:**

  - Triggers are fired when a *property* changes its *value*.
  - VisualStates are fired when the *control* request a *state* of a *group of states*.
- **Action they perform when they are fired:**

  - *Triggers:*

    1. Establish through `Setter` some other property.
  - *VisualState*:

    1. Initiates a status change request to `VisualStateManager`.
    2. `VisualStateManager` performs a `VisualTransition` before setting the state.
    3. `VisualTransition` performs a `Storyboard`.
    4. When a time specified by `GeneratedDuration` (of `VisualTransition`) has passed, `VisualStateManager` updates the `CurrentState` property of the corresponding `VisualStateGroup` of the control.
    5. Next, `VisualStateManager` performs the initial `VisualState` requested in (1).
    6. And finally, `VisualState` performs another `Storyboard`.

And yes, you're right to think that VisualStateManager makes the scenario more complex than Triggers. However, the complexity of VisualStateManager allows the programmer to do things that Triggers can't do (not in a simple way):

- **Make a difference between a state and a state transition:**

  - Generate animations during the state change independent of the state itself without generate another extra property.
  - Allow reuse the same transition by correctly setting of `From` and `To` commands of a `VisualTransition`.
  - Automatically control visual problems and animations (such as stopping a transition animation and activating another one in the middle of the transition).
  - Easy to add/edit/maintain/remove complex animations, which facilitates programming in complex scenarios.
- **Gives greater freedom in the way of firing a VisualState:**, since it can be made with a property changed, events, methods, etc. Even (this is the most magical thing) *without getting out of xaml*, using `Behavior` correctly.
- **Implement multiple states and state transitions simultaneously:** since you can assign a set of state groups to a control (a `VisualStateGroup`), and each state group has a unique `CurrentState` at a given time. Perhaps an image says it best:
  [image: State-Based Navigation QuickStart Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF]
- **Natural integration with WPF:** since, implicitly, the control is the one that handles the states, and allows to control the states in a sort of arrangement of tree of controls (parent-control), something that occurs naturally in WPF. This allows you to generate very complex scenarios with only a couple of lines; and of course, without touching the code behind of the control.

And I'm pretty sure there are more advantages. The most interesting thing is that if you would like to do some of these advantages on your own using Triggers, you will eventually fall into a system very similar to VisualStateManager ... try it!

### However ... it is not good to always use VisualStateManager

Even with all these advantages, the Triggers system should not be discarded by the VisualStateManager system. Triggers is a simpler system, but it also has its potential.

Personally, I would use Triggers for very simple "primitive" controls which do not require strange behavior or strange animations. In this type of controls the implementation complexity of VisualStateManager doesn't justify its use.

For more complex controls I would use VisualStateManager, especially on those "complex" controls that make use of other "primitive" controls (*note the meaning of the concept of "primitive" and "complex"*). Naturally this controls have a complex behavior according to user interaction.

Answer (score 9):

There is a huge amount of overlap between the two.  `VisualStateManager` was added later after dealing with the "pain" that can arise from using triggers for complex scenarios.  In general, it's much more flexible and easier to use.

Answer (score 7):

Some things are easier to do with triggers, others are easier with the VSM.

The biggest reason to use the VSM is that Triggers are not supported in Silverlight. If you ever expect to transition to Silverlight, stay away from Triggers.

Two drawbacks to VSM:

- You can't easily set the start state. The best method is to set it in the code behind somewhere, but it is painful.
- Animating the same property in two different state groups is not recommended, but is often desirable when implementing control templates. You can get more granularity in state overlaps with triggers because you can use multiple conditions.

VSM seems to be the future though. If you are using Blend, the VSM is very easy to configure.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use VisualStateManager(VSM) to create control contract for the parts as global design solution and trigger as reaction of view element in the particular case it is used.

It's a good practice to implement custom control describing its view as "state machine" and internal logic of transition.
But Triggers can react on changes of the surrounding controls, or application data.

I think you can use VisualStateManager when you develop custom control and Triggers when you develop complex view with multiple controls.

I disagree that the biggest reason to use VSM - unsupported Triggers in Silverlight. You can use Triggers from Microsoft.Expression.Interaction+System.Windows.Interactivity from Blend SDK. In Silverlight 5 this functionality will be available in silverlight core.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, it is easier to build a "design" experience around the visual states, that with triggers. For example, Expression Blend allows you to [interactively build](http://kokchiann.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/visual-state-manager-new-feature-of-expression-blend/) the storyboard that will be run for the various visual states ([video](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ee426922.aspx) for Blend 3). That cannot be done easily with triggers.