# Animating things in WPF - name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'

Tags: wpf, styling

Been trying to make a tabcontrol with some animation when changing tabs but it keeps giving me grief and refusing to let me put the animation in any useful place unless it's in the same XAML window file as the control itself (the style resides in a DLL file from which other styles work). Here's my style:

```
<Style x:Key="AnimatedTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border>
                        <TabPanel
                                IsItemsHost="True">
                        </TabPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                BorderBrush="White"
                                Background="White">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="TabControlContent" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="0" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="TabSelectionChangedStoryboard">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlContent"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To="100"
                         From="0"
                         FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                         Duration="0:0:30.0" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SelectionChanged">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TabSelectionChangedStoryboard}" />
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This results in 'TabControlContent' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'

I've also tried to move the animation to the beginning of the file, which results in the same error. If I put it after the style, the storyboard can't find it. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I just imported your Xaml into a project and it worked fine unamended.  In fact, it's a very nice style.  I'm using VS2010 with SP1, and received no warnings or errors.

Comment: It might be the fact that it's part of my style/controls/utils library which is imported. It seems to work if I stash this style in a window in the program, but if I load it from a DLL file I get that error.

Comment: No matter how much I move things around, I cannot get this to work while inside a DLL, but it will work in any setup declared in <Window.Resources> in the window XAML itself. Is this because of how WPF handles its threads or something? One would think that since it's all declared in the <ControlTemplate.Resources>, it ought to work?

Googled more and found a few other solutions which don't really apply here (it's not a usercontrol). Is it possible to store a <ContentPresenter> in the <ControlTemplate.Resources> and then place it where it should be in the border? If so, how do you do it? :P

Answer (score 6):

#### Solution:

use `Storyboard.Target` instead of `Storyboard.TargetName` in combination with `{Binding ElementName=TabControlContent`.

replace

```xml
<DoubleAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetName="TabControlContent"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    To="100"
    From="0"
    FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
    Duration="0:0:30.0" />
```

with

```xml
<DoubleAnimation 
    Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=TabControlContent}"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    To="100"
    From="0"
    FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
    Duration="0:0:30.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I search on web a lot but did not found appropriate answer... and after four days try `Finally` completed this way...

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GeneralButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="{StaticResource ButtonGeneral}" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Border x:Name="BorderFocused" Opacity="0"  Background="{StaticResource ButtonFocused}" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Border x:Name="BorderPressed"  Opacity="0" Background="Purple" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Border x:Name="BorderDisabled"  Opacity="0" Background="{StaticResource ButtonDisabled}" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="MainContent" Margin="20,5"  >
            <TextElement.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"></SolidColorBrush>
            </TextElement.Foreground>
            <TextElement.FontSize>
                16
            </TextElement.FontSize>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderFocused" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.01"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderFocused" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderFocused" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.01"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderFocused" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderPressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.01"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderPressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderDisabled" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderDisabled" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I know this is a few years old, but this helped me tremendously. Thank you!

Comment: Oh man, I used x:Key instead of x:Name. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the "VisualStateManager", at the following link you will find a brief explanation of the differences between "VisualStateManager" and "Triggers".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41030110/13037386

This shows how the graphic states are detached from triggers.